# Issues with custom audio player JS & CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio

I am trying to create a page with 12 different sound files and the ability to use a custom audio-player to play, pause, progress, and mute for each file. I have created a custom audio-player class, but the only way I can get each file to work is to give them their own ID and then call a new function every time. Is there a cleaner way to do this instead of having the same function repeated 12 times?

**HTML**

```
<div id="column1">   
<ol>
    <li>
    <span class="name">Diaphragmatic Breathing</span>           
    <span class ="info"> -  Dr. Allan Vives,  Georgia Southern University</span> 
    <span class="time">(<a class = "readmore" href="http://studentsupport.georgiasouthern.edu/counseling/resources/self-help/relaxation-and-stress-management/" target="_blank"> Read More</a>, 9:15 Mins, 12.6MB)</span>

      <div class="audio-player">
      <audio id="audio-player" src="../audio/breathing/Diaphragmatic Breathing.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls"></audio>
      </div>        
    </li>
    </ol>

</div>    
<div id="column2">
    <ol>
        <li>
        <span class="name">Breathing Relaxation Exercise 4-6-8 </span>          
        <span class ="info"> - Jason Sackett, University of Southern California</span> 
        <span class="time">(<a class = "readmore" href="http://www.usc.edu/programs/cwfl/wellness/relaxation.html" target="_blank"> Read More</a>, 2:33 Mins, 2.9MB)</span>

          <div class="audio-player1">
          <audio id="audio-player" src="../audio/breathing/breathing_relaxation_exercise-4-6-8.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls"></audio>
          </div>        
        </li>


    </ol>
</div>   

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#audio-player1').mediaelementplayer({
    alwaysShowControls: true,
    features: ['playpause', 'progress','volume'],
    audioWidth: 450,
    audioHeight: 70,
    iPadUseNativeControls: true,
    iPhoneUseNativeControls: true,
    AndroidUseNativeControls: true
  });
});

</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#audio-player2').mediaelementplayer({
    alwaysShowControls: true,
    features: ['playpause', 'progress','volume'],
    audioWidth: 450,
    audioHeight: 70,
    iPadUseNativeControls: true,
    iPhoneUseNativeControls: true,
    AndroidUseNativeControls: true
  });
});

</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#audio-player3').mediaelementplayer({
    alwaysShowControls: true,
    features: ['playpause', 'progress','volume'],
    audioWidth: 450,
    audioHeight: 70,
    iPadUseNativeControls: true,
    iPhoneUseNativeControls: true,
    AndroidUseNativeControls: true
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried just giving them all the same class and then targeting that?

Comment: You can also save the controls into a single object instead of having to recreate them for every single one. `var playerOptions = {
    alwaysShowControls: true,
    features: ['playpause', 'progress','volume'],
    audioWidth: 450,
    audioHeight: 70,
    iPadUseNativeControls: true,
    iPhoneUseNativeControls: true,
    AndroidUseNativeControls: true
  };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using an `id` for each element, give them all the same class and then you only need to do this once:

```
$(function(){
  $('.className').mediaelementplayer({
    alwaysShowControls: true,
    features: ['playpause', 'progress','volume'],
    audioWidth: 450,
    audioHeight: 70,
    iPadUseNativeControls: true,
    iPhoneUseNativeControls: true,
    AndroidUseNativeControls: true
  });
});
```

Where `.className` is whatever class you chose to give the elements.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I've been looking at this for too long. :)

Comment: Disregard my original comment. Your solution worked!

Answer (score 0):

Or if you don't want to touch the markup, you could **just change** your selector from

```
$("#audio-player1").mediaelementplayer({ ... });
```

To

```
// add this range generator
var fn = function(t,n,i){ return i>=n ? (t+n+" "+fn(t,n+1,i)) : ""; }
// use it to get a selector for all elements matching the resulting pattern
$(fn("#audio_player",1,12)).mediaelementplayer({ ... });
```